# hypothetical measure of variability similar to entropy

Tags: variance, mathematical-statistics, entropy

Variance has the following properties:

1. $Var(cX)=c^2Var(X)$
2. For independent variables $Var(X+Y)=Var(X)+Var(Y)$.

Range of a rv has the following properties:

1. $Range(cX)=|c| Range(X)$
2. For independent variables $Range(X+Y)=Range(X)+Range(Y)$.

Entropy has the following properties:

1. $H(cX)=H(X)$
2. For independent variables $H(X,Y)=H(X)+H(Y)$.

My main question: Does there exist a *characteristic* of a random variable such that:

1. $New(cX)=New(X)$
2. For independent variables $New(X+Y)=New(X)+New(Y)$.

?

(the only difference is "plus" instead of a vector random variable)

Maybe something can be said if the first property is replaced by $New(cX)=|c|^3New(X)$?

Comment: Almost by definition, "variability" reflects the value of $c$ (it's a scale factor). Therefore *no* measure that has your property (1) has any claim to be related to variability.

Comment: I agree, maybe the variability is the wrong word.

Comment: What, then, is your question?

Comment: I've replaced the word "variability" by "characteristic"

Comment: So you are looking for any scale "invariant" (not really the right wording) characteristic, which is also a measure (ie. with Countable additivity) ?

Answer (score 8):

### A characteristic with the desired properties (almost)

Variance is the second central moment: $$Var(x)=E(X-\mu)^2.$$
So when trying to find a characteristic that satisfies conditions 1 and 2, a natural first guess could be the third central moment:$$\mu_3(X)=E(X-\mu)^3.$$
By expanding the cube, it can be verified (I recommend that you try it!) that $\mu_3$ has the following properties, which are close to what you were hoping for:

1. Homogeneity: $\mu_3(cX)=c^3\mu_3(X)$
2. Additivity: $\mu_3(X+Y)=\mu_3(X)+\mu_3(Y)$ when $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

---

### Beyond the third moment

At this point you would perhaps guess that for the $k$:th central moment $$\mu_k(X)=E(X-\mu)^k$$ it holds that

1. $\mu_k(cX)=c^k\mu_k(X)$
2. $\mu_k(X+Y)=\mu_k(X)+\mu_k(Y)$ when $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

This is however **not** the case. There is however a characteristic $\kappa_k$, of which the variance and the third central moments are special cases, that has both the homogeneity and additivity properties. This $\kappa_k$ is called the $k$:th [cumulant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant). It is derived from the logarithm of the [moment-generating function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function) $E(e^{Xt})$:

$$ \mbox{log}(E(e^{Xt}))=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \kappa_k\frac{t^n}{n!}. $$

As an example, the above formula can be used to see that
$$\kappa_2(X)=Var(X)\\\kappa_3(X)=\mu_3(X)\\\mbox{and}\\\kappa_4(X)=\mu_4(X)-3Var(X)^2.$$

The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant) page for cumulants contains a lot more information about them.